# User account activation via SMS

Tags: users, activation

I would like to ask if there is a plugin or module that can activate/verify user account via SMS for Craft 4?

I found a plugin called [Validateit](https://plugins.craftcms.com/validateit?craft4) but its not yet compatible with Craft 4.

I would like to ask if you have any suggestion or recommendation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing I’m aware of, I’m afraid.

The ValidateIt plugin you linked to doesn’t appear to have anything to do with 2FA or SMS - it seems like a plain text field validator.

There is a [Porter plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/two-factor-authentication?craft4) for Craft 4 that says it does magic link authentication, which is kind of a form of MFA.

There is also [Two Factor Authentication](https://plugins.craftcms.com/two-factor-authentication?craft4), which does time-based authenticator MFA.